# Однородные и неоднородные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли так расставить знаки препинания в этом ряду определений?

Мы реализовали ряд своих концепций развития сложного (,) наукоемкого технологического и метрологического оборудования, вышло из печати три монографии – одна в единоличном авторстве и две в соавторстве.

Также:

Мы связываем это с разработкой новых (,) наукоемких технологий и оборудования...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Выбор за автором. Сложный и наукоёмкий - однородные определения, характеризующие оборудование как сложное в производстве - процесс многоэтапный и требующий научных знаний. Но можно увидеть и разность качеств, если захотеть: там сложно изготавливать, а здесь много знать.

Во втором я бы не ставила запятую: Мы связываем это с разработкой новых  наукоемких технологий и оборудования...Это разные качества, но в данном контексте возможно увидеть уточнение. Однако при уточняющих определениях знаки препинания чаще всего ставятся как при однородных определениях, то есть вторую запятую не ставят: Мы связываем это с разработкой новых,наукоемких технологий и оборудования...

Так что если и раньше были наукоёмкие - запятой нет. Если раньше были не наукоёмкие, а новые - наукоёмкие, то нужно уточнение, какие именно новые, запятую ставим.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Со вторым случаем более менее понятно. А вот касательно первого случая в Нацкорпусе нет ни одного совпадения с прилагательными **новых** и **наукоемких** с запятой между ними.

Comment: По Нацкорпусу грамотность, особенно пунктуацию, проверять нельзя, это писатели, люди творческие, у них много авторских знаков препинания.